# Mock a method in the same class being tested

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I want to mock a method in the same class that I am testing.

```
ClassA {
   function hardToTest($arg) {
      // difficult to test code
   }

   function underTest() {
      return $this->hardToTest('foo');
   }
}
```

I was thinking that I could use reflection to do this, but maybe it is just a sign that I should move `hardToTest` into another object.

Comment: I'm using PhpUnit 5.7, and I needed to use `createPartialMock` and specify which methods need to be mocked.

Comment: I agree that having to mock a method in the same class being tested is code smell, and that the method should be moved into another class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This test will succeed if `underTest()` passes `'foo'` to `hardToTest()`. This is known as a *partial mock* in PHPUnit's documentation because you are mocking only some of the methods.

```
ClassATest {
    function testUnderTest() {
        $mock = $this->getMock('ClassA', ['hardToTest']);
        $mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('hardToTest')
             ->with('foo');
        $mock->underTest();
    }
}
```

I agree with your instincts that this need may be a code smell telling you that this class is doing too much.

**PHPUnit 5.4+**

Since `getMock()` was deprecated in 5.4, use `getMockBuilder()` instead:.

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassA')
             ->setMethods(['hardToTest'])    // onlyMethods in 8.4+
             ->ge‌​tMock();
```

Comment: actually it should be `$mock = $this->getMock('ClassA', [ 'hardToTest' ]);`
second parameter of `getMock` is expected to be an array of method names.

Comment: In some cases you will need to do a partial mock, for example, if one of the class methods makes a HTTP request. It would be good to mock that method and return a stub for the request.

Comment: now that getMock is deprecated, how can we do this ?

Comment: @julestruong We haven't upgraded in a while since the API keeps changing.

Comment: @julestruong `$this->getMockBuilder(class)->setMethods(['methodName'])->getMock();`

Comment: Agree with you that is is a code smell. Whenever you have to mock method from same class, it time to think about moving it into independent class. It will make your tests much easier. I suffered this.

Comment: you may also use `$this->getMockBuilder('ClassA')->setConstructorArgs([$arg1, $arg2])`

Comment: A different query, if anyone can answer then please do. 
As everyone is saying that if we need to mock a method from same class being tested it should be moved to a new class.
Then during testing, we will need to mock the method of other class. Can we do that without dependency injection?

Comment: but what if the method I want to mock is a protected "setter" for some class internal settings, later needed to perform api-requests, witch is called by the constructor of the class under test?

Answer (score 0):

What I resorted was creating a sub class of my system under test with the relevant method stubbed out.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly is the reason what method is hard to test ?

If the method is protected, and you really really want to test it, then you can just extend your ClassA and make the `hardToTest($arg)` public.

The bottom line is that you shouldn't modify the class only because you need to write unittest for it. And in general, the `private` and `protected` methods should not be tested - you should test only the public interface.

Comment: I need to test a method that calls another method in THE SAME CLASS. I would like to be able to mock the functionality for that method at runtime. Moving the method into another class is not my preferred option.

Comment: yes thats pretty close to the idea....create a subclass of the system under test and stub out the relevant methods i don't want to test. thanks  for help

Comment: PlusOne for you mentioning _The bottom line_

Comment: "The bottom line is that you shouldn't modify the class only because you need to write unittest for it." 
A class (or code) which cannot be unit tested, is a badly written class (or code).